# How to move data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 and append Sheet 1 data above old Sheet 2 data

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having an issue getting my data from `s = ss.getSheetByName('Last Seven Days');` to append to the top of `ts = tss.getSheetByName('History');`. My xp in this area is very low so may need a bit of hand-holding while I get my head around it.

Currently I can only get my function saveToHistory to append the data from 'Last Seven Days' to the bottom of the 'History Sheet' with the below script:

```
function saveToHistory() {
  var ss, s, r, v, target,ts,tss;
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  s = ss.getSheetByName('Last Seven Days');
  if (s.getRange(2, 1).getValue()) {  
    tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ts = tss.getSheetByName('History'); // destination Sheet tab name
    s.getRange("A2:W").moveTo(ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1)); // Added
  }
}
```

Is there a .getFirstRow ?? or something that would have that effect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

1. Get the data from last 7 days `var lastSevenDays = sheet1.getValues();`
2. Get the data from the history sheet `var history = sheet2.getValues();`
3. Clear the history sheet `sheet2.clear();`
4. Concatenate the data form the history sheet to the last 7 days `lastSevenDays.concat(history);`
5. Write the combined data back to the sheet. `sheet2.setValues(lastSevenDays);`

Your final code would look like this:

(Assuming you have header on both tables and the width of the data is the same)

```
function moveToHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lastSevenDays = ss.getSheetByName("Last Seven Days");
  var history = ss.getSheetByName("History");

  var historyDataWithoutHeader = history.getDataRange().getValues();
  historyDataWithoutHeader.shift(); //This removes the first row (the header)

  var finalData = lastSevenDays.getDataRange().getValues().concat(historyDataWithoutHeader);

  history.getRange(1, 1, finalData.length, finalData[0].length).setValues(finalData);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks mate! This has worked like a charm! Hopefully, this answer can be of use now for someone else encountering the same problem :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful! Remember to accept the answers that are helpful to you! This way others can find these resources easier/faster.