# Is it possible to remove rows from several sheets at once (archiving)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a staff training database in Google Sheets. One staff member will appear in several sheets.

I want to add a column in the Master Sheet next to the column of staff names and add a Yes/No dropdown in that column so that when that staff member leaves the firm, the Yes dropdown is activated and all rows relating to that staff member are cut and pasted into sheets with duplicated headings and the blank cells where the original data lay are deleted.

Is this possible? Can someone help me with formula or code?

Below is a link to a copy of the database:

[Database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16tq-m2jhvxoi6sL8A0C_Fkx6BoNeaeFZzNQTM_zc06A/edit?usp=sharing)

The dropdown is in Column K of the 'Manage Staff' sheet. Do I need to create duplicates of each sheet with the active staff first so that the archived rows can be transferred?

Comment: This is definitely possible. You can make use of the `onEdit(e)` function to ensure the script runs based on users selecting Yes/No from the dropdown. It would help if you could share whatever you've coded so far so SO community can help build from there on forward.

Comment: In addition to explaining what you've coded so far (as @SourabhChoraria asks), please share your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Adding to @ SourabhChoraria and @Tedinoz' comments, it might be a good idea to check out the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the site so that people are able to help you from the get go. Asking for help, especially with Sheet integration, without providing code and file examples is a daunting request for users and you're unlikely to get answers.

Comment: Whether you tie it to this question or not, your database seriously needs to be normalised.

Comment: @Tedinoz - what do you mean, normalised?

Comment: @Sourabh Choraria - I have added a sample of my database with the private data changed

Comment: @McChief You appear to repeat a lot of data on each sheet and that can lead to errors. Normalisation is the process of reducing data redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an [`onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that:
 - Checks if the current edit is one that should trigger the copy
 - Copies the data to the backup sheet
 - Delete the data from the source.

Here are some resources to help you:

- [Example of how to move data from one sheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392374/11869748)
- [Detect which cell was updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560898/11869748)

Hope this helps!