# Is there a way to update this script so it only runs when a cell in a specific column is edited instead of any cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets problem: I need to show the difference between a cell's new value and its previous value to set a TRUE value if the difference is greater than x. At the moment, I'm using this script (sorry, I can't get this to format correctly!):

```
function previous() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var source = ss.getRange('sheet1!B2:B');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('sheet2!C2:C'), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Using a trigger, I set this up to run whenever an edit occurs, however, I only want it to run when a cell in column B is edited.

Is this possible?

I've tried adding in a `range.GetColumn()` section to the script, however, I'm new to scripts and I'm not sure of the syntax required (or even if this will work).

Comment: Give the function a parameter to hold the event object. Then use if(e.range.columnStart==2)

Comment: You should also consider using something like if(e.range.getSheet().getName()==‘Sheet Name”) to limit the action to one sheet or tab.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use the [`onEdit(e)` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) and use the parameter that is added by default ([`e`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)).

That object has a property called range (`e.range`) that is of type [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

Inside the function you can then check if that Range is within the column you want to check.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn()==3) {//for column C, as an example
     //execute here
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As the OP is using an installable on edit trigger, there is no need to use a simple trigger, just use the event object  and the condition that you suggested.